# latex - lyx: how to change automatically some field in a document

Tags: lyx, latex3

Sorry but I'm a newbie in Latex and Lyx. I need to have a field referenced in the whole document. For example a character's name in a short novel. I need to be able to change that name wherever in the document from a single entry point.
I tried to search in the documentation or google but without success.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In my opinion, it is a problem for the editor?

Comment: should be if I was a pro writer. This was just an example.

Comment: Didn't you misunderstand me? I meant the text editor dedicated to latex.

Comment: yes, very misunderstood. Sorry. Did you meand something like search/replace?
however I'd like to now if there is a features of Latex or better LyX that I use.

Comment: For LaTeX, I don't know any. Maybe it's possible with a tricky coding.  As to LyX, I never used it, so I can't say.

Comment: ok, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Document > Settings > LaTeX Preamble and put something like:

```
\newcommand{\bobsname}{bobby}
```

Then click "OK". Then in your text, whenever you want to use the name, you can press Ctrl + L (at least this is the shortcut on Linux), or Insert > TeX Code and inside you can put `{\bobsname}`.

Edit: replaced `\bobsname` with `{\bobsname}` (thanks @barbara beeton).

Comment: If `\bobsname` is wrapped in braces -- `{\bobsname}` -- in the text, there won't be any spacing problems, which might otherwise occur especially for a newbie.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks! I edited in the improvement.